# What is the full list of ways to modify a primitive?

Tags: javascript

I am writing some syntactical analyzer that disallows changing a primitive.

So I know that one can modify primitives these ways:

```
let p // a primitive

p = 1
p += 1
p -= 1
p %= 1
p *= 1
```

Is it really a full, exhaustive list of ways to change a primitive? Or did I forget something...

P.S. The analyzer is for my peculiar library. It disallows to change a passed argument to a function that returns an object literal of test closures, i.e. each closure must not change their common primitive.

Comment: you miss the other [assingment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), like `%=`, `*=`, etc.

Comment: How silly is it! Indeed, I forgot to include these

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Primitives are immutable, you don't change them, you replace them (by assigning a new value). In regard to [assignment operators](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-assignment-operators), the full list is `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `+=`, `-=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `>>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, `|=`, `**=`.

Comment: and you miss some new [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) techniques.

Comment: @RobG Wow. This seems what I need. Want to post an answer? Also can you provide the source. Is it just from your brain/memory?

Comment: `const` also disallows changing primitives. Why the static analyzer?

Comment: @JonasWilms are your sure? How/when is it possible? The analyzer is for my peculiar library. It disallows to change a passed argument.

Comment: ... additionally `eval("p = 5")`

Comment: or [function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you so much, can you elaborate on function constructor?

Comment: [MDN - Assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Overview) and don't forget the Increment (`++`) and Decrement (`--`) operators

Comment: @JonasWilms At first I misread your comment as "const also **allows** changing primitives". Hence I asked, "are your sure". Added to the answer why I need this.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! Almost forgot about (in/de)crement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 // assignment operators
 p = 1; 
 p += 1;
 p -= 1;
 p *= 1;
 p /= 1;
 p %= 1;
 p <<= 1;
 p >>= 1;
 p >>>= 1;
 p &= 1; 
 p ^= 1;
 p |= 1;
 p **= 1;
 // decrement / increment operators
 p++;
 ++p;
 p--;
 --p;
// destructuring
({ p } = { p: 1 });
({ a: p } = { a: 1 });
([p] = [1]);
```

Note that all of the above could also occur in a parsed string:

```
 (new Function("p = 1"))();
 eval("p = 1");
```

> The analyzer is for my peculiar library. It disallows to change a passed argument.

Then I guess the easiest is to just parse:

```
 function toTest(p) { /* body */ }
```

to this and execute it:

```
 const p = 1;
 try {
   eval(/* body */);
} catch(e) {
  //...
}
```

If an error occurs, someone tried to mutate the const.

Comment: If only I could vote a hundred times. Thanks for elaborating about what @NinaScholz meant (function constructor)

Comment: There are other ways, e.g. with [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/), which is too long to fit in a comment but starts with: `[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![…`

Comment: @Jonas oh my god you are my savior. I think you saved me few days, at least! Great approach with const.

Comment: @Biffen Lol. Indeed one could do something like this. Thanks for reminding! However I'll ignore such cases, because my lib is for running/executing tests, and there is no some security issue with this, i.e. I can really ignore some users trying to shoot in their foot.